# Same color but looks different in different font size

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I use the same color but it looks different in font size.
It looks like the bigger size has the darker color.
Is that normal or is there anything I need to adjust?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you set them differently in the Storyboard.

You better put your code here, so that we can help you.

If you set your text in different font size, it may look a little different. It a problem of visual. You can set them to the same size, so you can compare color.

Comment: I set everything on Storyboard and didn't code anything. I am pretty sure it's the same color and I chose the system color only not the custom color.  I wish I can post image here so it can explain more clearly. Unfortunately, I am new here so I am not allowed to post an image.

Comment: thanks. If the font size are the same, there is no problem. What i suffer is the visual problem. So It's normal and I can't do anything for this, right?